# Export deeplearning4j models to Keras

Tags: keras, deeplearning4j

I know deeplearning4j can import models from Keras ( https://deeplearning4j.org/model-import-keras ), but I'm interested in the opposite way. Therefore,

- is there any way to export deeplearning4j models to Keras?

This could be either directly or by somehow converting a model stored using the ModelSerializer https://deeplearning4j.org/modelpersistence )? In particular, I would be interested in using trained models in keras.js ( https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js ).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not yet.  We would be happy to take a pull request though!

Comment: I beat for that!

Comment: Sorry still only model import. Still happy to take PRs. It's just not the top of our list. People typically deploy their models with dl4j not train models. File a github issue (eg: not somewhere where the maintainers barely read) and talk to us directly and we will see what we can do.